# UFW - Allow outgoing traffic to a range?

Tags: ubuntu, ufw

I'm attempting to restrict outbound 443 traffic from a server to a set of subnets. When I write the tuple rules in my user.rules file, this looks like it should work, however no traffic is being allowed to the subnet. Does UFW not allow ranges in destinations?

`### tuple ### allow tcp 443 X.X.X.0/24 any 0.0.0.0/0 out`

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that while ufw doesn't seem to know how to work with destination ranges, if you follow up the tuple line with and iptables line, it will work.

```
### tuple ### allow tcp 443 X.X.X.0/24 any 0.0.0.0/0 out
-A ufw-user-output -p tcp --dport 443 -m iprange --dst-range X.X.X.0-X.X.X.255 -j ACCEPT
```